# PayPal REST API security questions

Tags: security, rest, paypal

I am concerned about PayPal's new REST API security. I have developed simple web application with it (direct card payment using vault and payment with Paypal account), but I am wondering:

1. I've noticed that there are no signature generated from request's content which is passed with each REST API request, so that PayPal's server can be sure that there is content in request which is not changed along the way by unauthorized person.
2. How is that secured from repeated API requests? I think this is solved in Classic API by including some timestamp which is signed and stuff like that.. But how it is secured in new REST API?

These are questions that are occurred to me, and if you have some other security concerns please tell us...?

Answer (score 2):

1. The API is protected from man-in-the-middle attacks by exclusively using HTTPS to encrypt communication with the server.
2. HTTPS also protects you from replay attacks.

Signed hashes and timestamps are useful for tackling these problems when HTTPS is not desirable (usually because you want to be able to cache responses).

Comment: Your answer is useful! So, according to your first answer, HTTPS encryption takes care of that.. But I think that in Classic API we used salted hash, generated with secret key, which took care of it.. Why there is suddenly no need for that any more?

Answer (score 0):

To ensure idempotency (protection against repeated API request), you can set the PayPal-Request-Id header. See https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#authentication--headers